# AJAX Variable data

Tags: php, ajax

I have question with ajax.

my ajax script :

```
{
  "data": "noInduk",
  "width": "100px",
  "sClass": "text-center",
  "orderable": false,
  "mRender": function(data) {
    return '<a href="data.php?noInduk="' + data + '"">Edit</a>';
  }
```

How to do this so that I can make more than one variable to review the data request.

```
 return '<a href="data.php?noInduk="'+ data + '"">Edit</a>';
```

be like this

```
 return '<a href="data.php?noInduk="'+ data + '"/"'+ data2 + '"">Edit</a>';
```

Comment: Please share more of your code.

Comment: Return only data; Process the data in the calling part

Comment: please share more code of data.php

Answer (score 0):

One solution is that get the whole data with concatenating with a specific delimiter like | and on ajax response split data, so you will have two responses.

```
{
"data": "noInduk",
"width": "100px",
"sClass": "text-center",
"orderable": false,
"mRender": function(data) {
var  newData = data.split('|');
'<a href="data.php?noInduk="'+ newData[0] + '"/"'+ newData[1]+ '"">Edit</a>'; 
}
```